# Attempted to load class in Symfony Kernel

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've got a problem to load two of my bundles.

In the `psr-4 block`

```
"BackBundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/BackBundle",
"FrontBundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/FrontBundle",
```

In the require block

```
"myvendor/frontbundle": "1.0.0",
"myvendor/backbundle": "1.0.0",
```

Here is the path for the back bundle class ( same for the front ):

```
vendor/MyVendor/backbundle/BackBundle.php
```

I call the two bundles in the `AppKernel.php`

```
new \backbundle\BackBundle(),
new \frontbundle\FrontBundle(),
```

The namespaces are backbundle and frontbundle

When I run the `s:r command`, it returns :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FrontBundle" from namespace "frontbundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\pathToProject\app\AppKernel.php:20
```

I tried

```
"BackBundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/backbundle",
"FrontBundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/frontbundle",
```

and

```
"backbundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/backbundle",
"frontbundle\\": "vendor/MyVendor/frontbundle",
```

with running `rm -rf var/cache/*` and `composer dump-autoload` it doesn't work.
Do you have any idea about the reason?

Comment: I'd assume this is a composer "problem". theoretically, you should not write the location of backbundle and frontbundle in your project's composer.json, but those namespaces have to be defined in the composer.json's of their respective libraries. to confirm, take a look into vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php (and other files there). if it doesn't contain your bundles, you have to fix the bundles. your composer.json should only have the `require` part.

Comment: If you look in the default composer.json you will see there is always a trailing forward slash on the right side of the assignment.  Also, the namespace for your bundles should be MyVendor/BackBundle.  So something like: "MyVendor\\BackBundle\\": "../vendor/myvendor/backbundle/"  But as mentioned below, if your bundles are composer packages and you installed them with composer then you should not need to do anything.

Comment: Please check for upper and lower case of directory names, file names, and class names. Additionally, how did you put the files in `vendor`? Through Composer, such that the autoloader is properly generated?

Answer (score 1):

If your bundles are composer packages you don’t need to register them in psr-4 block. You only need to register them /actually this should happen automatically upon installation/ in config/bootstrap.php.

The usage is like:

```
new MyVendor/FrontBundle/MyClass
```